# Run JUnit 4 Tests Twice With Different Configuration

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have collection of JUnit test classes currently. I would like to run all the tests I currently have but with different configurations.

So for instance in my code I have a class:

```
public class Storage {
    public static final int VERSION = 1;
}
```

and I would like to run all my unit tests with `Storage.VERSION` = 1, and then again for `Storage.VERSION` = 2.

Ideally I would do this with minimal code changes. I was looking through JUnit documentation in the hopes that perhaps I could create a parent class for all my unit test classes that changes the configuration between runs but don't see anything that easy. It looks like the theories idea could be used but would require adding annotations to every test class.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Sounds like you want a dependency injection framework.

Comment: @jsheeran Could you provide some example code using JUnit to illustrate what you mean? Just mentioning dependency injection is not very helpful.

Comment: If your goal is to run tests multiple times with different configurations, what about parameterized tests? Though that may result in many changes to your tests.

Comment: @NickDeFazio I'm just looking to alter the public variable in the class before running the test cases for a second time. I don't think Paramaterized tests really fit the bill.